# Fading doesn't work, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fading

It's very simple task, but somewhere is a mistake.. I can't find out it.

```
function get(obj) { return document.getElementById(obj); }
var SomeObj = {
    t1:null,t2:null,
    hide: function() {
        if(parseFloat(get("wr_st").style.opacity)>0.45) {
            get("wr_st").style.opacity-=0.05;
        } else {
            clearInterval(SomeObj.t1);
        }
    },
    show: function() {
        if(parseFloat(get("wr_st").style.opacity)<1) {
            get("wr_st").style.opacity+=0.05;
        } else {
            clearInterval(SomeObj.t2);
        }
    },
    fade: function($wt) {
        if($wt==1) {
            clearInterval(menu.status.t2);
            menu.status.t1=setInterval('SomeObj.hide();',10);
        } else if($wt==2) {
            clearInterval(menu.status.t1);
            menu.status.t2=setInterval('SomeObj.show();',10);
        }
    }
}
```

So, I have an input (type=text). With attributes:

```
onfocus="SomeObj.fade(1);" 
onblur="SomeObj.fade(2);".
```

Onblur doesn't work. More precisely, this doesn't work:

```
get("wr_st").style.opacity+=0.05;
```

If I'll place here for ex.: alert('NOOOO'); it will be always in process, because opacity+=0.5 doesn't work..
Can you help me: WTF is that & why it doesn't work? Thank you..

Comment: have you tried converting `.opacity` into an integer like so: `get("wr_st").style.opacity= parseInt( get("wr_st").style.opacity ) + 0.05`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a number to a string, which will convert the number to a string rather than converting the string to a number. If the current value is for example `"0.7"` you end up with `"0.70.05"` instead of `0.75`.

Parse the string before adding:

```
get("wr_st").style.opacity = (parseFloat(get("wr_st").style.opacity) + 0.05).toString();
```

(This of course is repeating the `get` call and the parsing more than neccesary, you can store immediate values in tempory variables to make the code less repetetive.)